# Seamless Procedural Texture is stretching

Tags: texturing

I'm using procedural texture coordinates with applied scale for the textures. 
How can I avoid horizontal distortion?

thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change the projection method option from 'flat' to 'box' in the image texture nodes.